# How to get the subscription id related to the current order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using woocommerce subscriptions and I'm writing a plugin to update an external system, if the user upgrade or downgrade his subscription it shows as a new order with its ID, but I can't get the subscription ID (which it's constant) related to the order ID, I check the documentation but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve like this.

```
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ));
foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription_obj )
{
   $current_subs_id = $subscription_obj->get_id(); // This is current subscription id
   $parent_id = $subscription_obj->get_parent_id(); // This is subscription parent id
}
```

Comment: You might also use \wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order->get_id(), array( 'subscriptions_per_page' => 1, 'order_type' => 'parent' ));

Answer (score 0):

You can access this data by hooking into the `processed_subscription_payment` action provided by WooCommerce Subscriptions:

```
add_action( 'processed_subscription_payment', 'se43079522_process_subscription', 10, 2 );

function se43079522_process_subscription($user_id, $subscription_key) {
    // here you have access to the $subscription_key (ID) and the $user_id associated
}
```

Take a look at this link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/ for more information on the available actions with this plugin.

OR, you can do this manually like so:

**Read comments for walk-through**

```
global $woocommerce;

// Get the order ID and save as variable
$order_id = [ORDER_ID];

// Get the order object
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

// Loop through the subscription order
foreach ( WC_Subscriptions_Order::get_recurring_items( $order ) as $order_item ) {

    // Get the subscription key
    $subscription_key = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_subscription_key( $order->id, WC_Subscriptions_Order::get_items_product_id( $order_item ) );

}

// This is your subscription key (ID)
echo $subscription_key;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, I can get the order id but I can't get the subscription ID using the functions above, I even copied and pasted the code from here without any changes just added the echo to see the results but there was no output at all, the error log is clean, is there anyway to track the php behavior and see which class/hook was activated during the process ?

Comment: Did you change out `[ORDER_ID]` with the proper ID for your order? How about try turning on `WP_DEBUG` in wp-config.php?

Comment: I did, I got it from 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' action and the echo printed it out but just the order id, the subscription id was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Get Subscription ID from Order. You can use wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order woocommerce function to get an object with the subscription related to that order and get the subscription ID from there.

$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($order_id);

var_dump($subscriptions);